# Does this question belong in Physics?

Tags: discussion, questions

I wrote a program that computes the fast **insert_name_here** transform of a matrix. I am at a loss of what its application is, what its proper name should be, and find an existing algorithm for it. I posted this question in Computer Science, and one of their members suggested it might be better served here. Does this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/what-can-i-do-with-this-algorithm) belong in Physics? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The question in the linked post is essentially *What is the primary algorithm that solves this problem?* which really isn't a physics question but an algorithm identification one. I also somewhat doubt that the question could be rewritten to be a physics question, but I could be wrong on that. So I would say, *No this would not be on topic here.*

The question as posed *could* be on topic at [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), which covers scientific programming, broadly speaking.